# Is there a way I can prevent an app from going to the home screen when orientation is changed?

Tags: android, layout, orientation, return, fixed

I snap a photo, and it gets placed onto an ImageView.  When the user sees the page where the Image View is, and I turn the phone sideways where the orientation is horizontal, the app immediately returns to the app's main screen.  Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android there are some detailed answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating the phone recreates the activity. Implementing the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` methods to properly save and restore the state of the activity should fix the problem.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance on that - but do you mean for each class?  I have super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in the class that it is changing orientation in, and it still goes back to the app's home screen.

Comment: What do you mean by homes screen? Does it switch to another activity? Does a popup disappear? Does the view get reset?

Comment: it goes from one of my classes called by setContentView back to my app's main class

Comment: Your activity is destroyed by default when you rotate the screen. If you always call `setContentView()` with the same view inside `onCreate()` it will always switch back to it.

Comment: If you are completely replacing the view perhaps it would be simpler to switch to another activity instead.